# Align div on bootstrap Tool Tip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tooltip

I generated code for an HTML view page, to show BS Tool Tip against each column in the table. The content of the Tool Tip, also table-like structure. I made it using divs, but on div has long content not aligned correctly as a table

can you help me to correct this change?

Severity level is the second row, the value against the severity level is the long one. I need to align the severity level against the starting of the corresponding value

[image]

HTML (generated through rails template)

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="" data-animation="true" data-original-title="
<div style = 'width:200px,'>
   <div class ='tool-tip-cells'>Repair Method </div>
   <div class ='tool-tip-cells'> Repaint </div><div class ='tool-tip-cells'>Severity Level</div>
   <div class ='tool-tip-cells'>Damage 2.5cm to 7.5cm in length and/or diameter</div>
   <div class ='tool-tip-cells'>Estimate No.</div>
  <div class ='tool-tip-cells'>9176863</div>
<div>">Rear Bumper RHS (Scuffed)</div>
```

CSS

```
.tool-tip-cells{
text-align: left;
width: 100px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can you fork that up in a jsfiddle or codepen please?

Comment: You probably just need to specify a proper `vertical-align` value to get the contents of all those “cells” properly lined up at the top ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

`vertical-align: text-top;`